# Implementing an RVM, results out of the window

Tags: python

So I'm currently working on a project to implement an RVM, and I thought I had done so until I saw my results, completely disasterous, the code that has been used is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.spatial import distance
#Kernel


def training_banana(name):
    inputs = []
    file = open(name, "r")
    for line in file:
        vector = line.split()
        coordinate = []
        for i in range(len(vector)):
            coordinate.append(float(vector[i]))
        inputs.append(coordinate)
    file.close()

    return np.array(inputs)


def define_inputs(name, name_targets):
    inputs = training_banana(name)
    targets_array = training_banana(name_targets)
    N = targets_array.shape[0]
    targets = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N):
        targets[i] = targets_array[i][0]
    return inputs, targets, N

#training set
inputs_train, targets_train, N = define_inputs('banana_train_data_2.asc', 'banana_train_labels_2.asc') # banana_train, banana_train_label
permute = list(range(N))
random.shuffle(permute)
inputs_train = inputs_train[permute, :]
targets_train = targets_train[permute]

#test set
inputs_test, targets_test, N = define_inputs('banana_test_data_2.asc', 'banana_test_labels_2.asc') #banana_test.txt, banana_test_label
permute = list(range(N))
random.shuffle(permute)
inputs_test = inputs_test[permute, :]
targets_test = targets_test[permute]


# Radial basis function
def rbf_kernel(x, y, sig=1):
    return np.exp(-1*(distance.euclidean(x,y)**2)/(2*sig**2))


# phi function as defined in Tipping eq. 4
# x: D-dimensional numpy array
# X_matrix: (D x N)-dimensional numpy array
def phi(x, X_matrix):
    ret = np.zeros(len(X_matrix)+1)
    for i in range(1, len(ret)):
        ret[i] = rbf_kernel(x, X_matrix[i - 1])
    ret[0] = 1
    return ret

# Generates a design matrix (Phi) according to Tipping eq. 4.
# X_matrix: (D x N) - matrix of points in feature space
def generate_design_matrix(X_matrix):
    res = np.zeros((len(X_matrix), len(X_matrix)+1))
    i = 0
    for point in X_matrix:
        res[i] = phi(point, X_matrix)
        if i < 1:
            print(point)
        i += 1
    return res

a = generate_design_matrix(inputs_train)
print(inputs_train)

def y(x, w, X_training):
    return np.matmul(np.transpose(w), phi(x, X_training))

def sigmoid_link_function(y):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-y))

def likelihood(t, x, w, X_training):
    return sigmoid_link_function(y(x, w, X_training))**t * (1 - sigmoid_link_function(y(x, w, X_training)))**(1 - t)

def classify(x, w, X_training):
    if likelihood(1, x, w, X_training) > likelihood(0, x, w, X_training):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def train_model(design_matrix, X_training, t_training, alpha_max):
    N = len(t_training)  # number of points
    alpha = np.ones(N + 1) * 0.8  # initial alpha-values (has been chosen rather arbitrarily)
    w_MP = np.zeros(len(alpha))
    for i in range(len(w_MP)):
        # since we assume that w follows an N(0, alpha^(-1) distribution, I choose the initial guesses for w like this.
        w_MP[i] = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(alpha[i]**(-1)))

    delta_thresh = 1e-20  # threshold for convergence assumption
    alpha_upper = alpha_max  # threshold for divergence assumption
    beta = np.zeros(N)
    gamma = np.zeros(len(alpha))
    converged = False
    alpha_done = np.zeros(len(alpha))  # keeps track of which alphas have either converged or diverged
    prune = np.zeros(len(alpha))  # keeps track of which alphas tend to inf, i.e. which weights can be pruned

    while not converged:
        A = np.diag(alpha)  # same as in regression
        for i in range(len(beta)):
            beta[i] = sigmoid_link_function( y(X_training[i], w_MP, X_training))* (1-sigmoid_link_function( y(X_training[i], w_MP, X_training) ))  # see Tipping eq. 25
        B = np.diag(beta)
        sigma_matrix = np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(np.transpose(design_matrix), np.matmul(B, design_matrix)) + A) # see Tipping eq. 26
        w_MP = np.matmul(sigma_matrix, np.matmul(np.transpose(design_matrix), np.matmul(B, t_training)))  # see Tipping eq. 27

        # alphas are updated according to Tipping eq. 16 (as in the case of regression)
        for i in range(len(alpha)):
            gamma[i] = 1 - alpha[i] * sigma_matrix[i, i]
            new_alpha = gamma[i] / (w_MP[i] ** 2)
            delta = new_alpha - alpha[i]
            if delta < delta_thresh:  # in this case, alpha_i has converged
                alpha[i] = new_alpha
                alpha_done[i] = 1
            elif np.abs(new_alpha) > alpha_upper:  # in this case, alpha is assumed tend to infinity
                alpha[i] = new_alpha
                prune[i] = 1
                alpha_done[i] = 1
            else:  # in this case, we just continue
                alpha[i] = new_alpha

        if len(alpha_done) == np.sum(alpha_done):  # will be True if all alphas are done
            converged = True

    # sigma_matrix and w_MP are updated one last time with the final alpha values
    A = np.diag(alpha)  # same as in regression
    for i in range(len(beta)):
        beta[i] = sigmoid_link_function(y(X_training[i], w_MP, X_training)) * (
                    1 - sigmoid_link_function(y(X_training[i], w_MP, X_training)))  # see Tipping eq. 25
    B = np.diag(beta)
    sigma_matrix = np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(np.transpose(design_matrix), np.matmul(B, design_matrix)) + A) #kanske ska vara - här
    w_MP = np.matmul(sigma_matrix, np.matmul(np.transpose(design_matrix), np.matmul(B, t_training)))

    # lastly, w_MP is pruned
    for i in range(len(w_MP)):
        if prune[i]:  # an alpha tending towards infinity leads to a zero weight
            w_MP[i] = 0

    return w_MP, sigma_matrix

design_matrix = generate_design_matrix(inputs_train) #kan stämma
w_MP, sigma_matrix = train_model(design_matrix, inputs_train, targets_train, 500)


def answer():
    corr_tar = []
    for i in range(inputs_test.shape[0]):
        corr_tar.append(classify(inputs_train[i],w_MP, inputs_train))
    correct = []
    for i in range(inputs_test.shape[0]):
        if corr_tar[i] == targets_train[i]:
            correct.append(1)
        else:
            correct.append(0)
    return sum(correct)/inputs_test.shape[0]

print(answer())
```

As you can see, I'm even using the training set once again as the test set, but no matter what I do, I keep ending up around 50-55 % correct (a fair coin would've been just as useful). I realize that I've done a huge error somewhere, but I can't figure out where. Any help in the matter would be hugely appreciated, I think I've gone blind on my own code.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue of where this did go wrong?

Comment: Can anyone just let me know if they are trying on the problem, if that's not the case (since I cannot solve this on my own due to my inability), I will abandon it.